# Join on RDD and map the values - constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to the world of Scala and Spark and hence need a little help.

I've two vals, both - `RDD[((String, String), Double)]`

and the values like:-

```
RDD1 = 
((a, b), 10)
((c, d), 20)
((g, h),50)

RDD2 = 
((a, b), 20)
((e, f), 30)
((g, h), 10)
```

and the desired output is:-

```
(a, b, 30)
(c, d, 20)
(e, f, 30)
(g, h, 60)
```

I'm sorry for posting the mock data due to some policies, but would really appreciate any help.

I tried:-

```
    val joined = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map{case(x, y, z) => (x._1, x._2, y+z)}

but seems I'm making some mistake. It shows error that:-
[error] ...../class.scala:59: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : (T1, T2, T3)
[error]  required: ((String, String), (Option[Double], Option[Double]))
[error]       val joined = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map{case(x, y, z) => (x._1, x._2, y._1+z._1)}
[error]                                                                    ^
[error] ...../class.scala:59: not found: value x
[error]       val joined = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map{case(x, y, z) => (x._1, x._2, y._1+z._1)}
[error]                                                                                  ^
[error] ...../class.scala:59: not found: value x
[error]       val joined = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map{case(x, y, z) => (x._1, x._2, y._1+z._1)}
[error]                                                                                        ^
[error] ...../class.scala:59: not found: value y
[error]       val joined = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map{case(x, y, z) => (x._1, x._2, y._1+z._1)}
[error]                                                                                              ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 25 Jul, 2018 6:54:09 PM
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as the `double` values are `Options`:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((("a","b"),10.0),
                          (("c","d"),20.0),
                          (("g","h"),50.0)))

val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((("a","b"),20.0),
                          (("e","f"),30.0),
                          (("g","h"),10.0)))

rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).map {case ((x1, x2), (y1, y2))  => (x1,x2,y1.getOrElse(0.0) + y2.getOrElse(0.0))}.collect.foreach(println)

//((g,h),60)
//((c,d),20)
//((e,f),30)
//((a,b),30)
```

Comment: Tried that but still it says     type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Double.type
[error]  required: String

Comment: I'm not sure about your datatypes. See the updated the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-line solution without having to join the RDDs :

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((("a","b"),10.0),
                      (("c","d"),20.0),
                      (("g","h"),50.0)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((("a","b"),20.0),
                      (("e","f"),30.0),
                      (("g","h"),10.0)))
```

Then we union the values of the different RDDs, and we sum the values of each key using reduceByKey :

```
val result = (rdd1 union rdd2).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

This is equivalent to the following line :

```
val result = (rdd1 union rdd2).reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
```

Let's check the output of the final result :

```
result.foreach(println)

//((e,f),30.0)
//((a,b),30.0)
//((g,h),60.0)
//((c,d),20.0)
```

I hope it helps !